# Container view with UITableView makes every child the same screen size

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, containers

The Job Table View Container makes the Job Table View Controller half the size on the screen, which is the desired result. But when I click a cell and it goes to Job Detail View Controller, it is still half the screen size. I don't want the Container to affect the Detail View Controller screen.

[image]

[image]
[image]

I tried this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    JobDetailViewController *jobDetailViewController = (JobDetailViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"jobDetailView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:jobDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

And this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"jobDetail"]) {

        [[segue destinationViewController]
         sendSelectedJobID:[self jobID]];
    }
}
```

**Answer:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-arrange the view hierarchy as follows:

Navigation Controller -> Job View Controller -> container -> Job table view controller

Also Pass the Navigation Controller reference to the Job table view controller.  That is update the table view's navigationController property to the Navigation Controller in use.